# neo4j List datatype

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wanted to know if there is an inbuilt method like append, etc to add to an end of the a property of type list.

So for e.g.

I have a node

```
CREATE (A:TEST{dateUpdated:[21312312,2121212],title:'title'})
```

and I want to append a ***new timestamp to the dateUpdated property*** which is of type list whenever the title gets added in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no** inbuilt support to work directly with array properties in Neo4j. You need to handle this in the application yourself. MongoDB, a document-oriented database supports this natively using [push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/)